# How to add a partial border to header title?

Tags: html, css

I have to add a stylish border in the header text like this:

[image]

but I'm not sure how to do it.

I tried the below code with `border-bottom` but it does not look good.

```css
h1 {
  font-size:30px;
  color:#000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Navigation</h1>
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could use a pseudo element positioned over the `border-bottom`:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

h1::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -6px; /* your padding + border-width */
}
```

```html
<h1>Navigation</h1>
```

Using a pseudo element like this makes it very easy to add animation. Perhaps to animate the border when hovering over a section of the page:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

h1::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -7px; /* your padding + border-width */
  transition: width .6s ease;
}

.section:hover h1::after {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <h1>Navigation</h1>

  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas aliquet accumsan odio, sit amet molestie tortor ultricies vel. Donec nibh purus, fermentum eget dolor ac, tincidunt scelerisque urna. Ut gravida id eros sed placerat. Etiam vel mi erat. Etiam rhoncus massa ultricies quam malesuada pretium. Fusce elementum diam in turpis rutrum auctor. Vestibulum venenatis bibendum euismod. Praesent ex justo, blandit non urna et, porta interdum enim.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 29):

With a pseudo-element and a linear-gradient

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
}

h1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -.5em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, gold 15%, grey 15%, grey);
}
```

```html
<h1>Navigation</h1>
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use a gradient and background-size

```css
h1 {
  font-size:30px;
  color:#000;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, gold 8em, #ccc 8em) bottom left no-repeat;/* here start/stop color is et at 8em, use your own value and colors */
  background-size:100% 3px;/* here set thickness */
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Navigation</h1>
```

Answer (score 8):

I took it a little further and made the heading look more like the reference image. I'm using the same background image idea as G-Cyr did in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46910451/3220986).
Note the two backgrounds. The first set of values in the `background` and `background-size` attributes are what make the bottom line; the second set is for the background color.

```css
h1 {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #E6831D 20%, #FFF 20%) bottom .5em left .8em no-repeat, linear-gradient(#323A45, #323A45);
  background-size: 100% 1px, 100% 100%;
  padding: .8em;
  color: #FDFFFE;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<h1>Awesome Heading</h1>
```

Answer (score 6):

One of the ways of doing so would be to add `h1::after` with required width - and having a different border color.

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFEB3B;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    POSITION: relative;
}

h1:after {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Navigation</h1>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using `:after` pseudo selector

```css
h1 {
  font-size:30px;
  color:#000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  position: relative;
}
h1:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -1px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Navigation</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

One method you could explore is using `pseudo-elements`.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

h1:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background: orange;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Navigation</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use pseudo selector `:before` to add that border, `h1` is a `block element` thus you even need to add `width` to customize the length of that border or else it will be 100% h1 width.

```css
h1{
  font-size:30px;
  color:#000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  position:relative;
}
h1:before{
  content:"";
  bottom:-1px;
  left:0;
  border-bottom:1px solid brown;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Navigation</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `:after` as well as `:before` pseudo elements to get exact output. Set them in `absolute` positioned. Check below snippet for reference.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #000;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

h1:after {
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Navigation</h1>
```